# ActiveRecord find_by query returning nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following object stored in my database:

```
<TenancyTenant id: 11, tenancy_id: 1, tenant_id: 1, created_at: "2017-03-15 14:30:44", updated_at: "2017-03-15 14:30:44">
```

When I use the following queries then the object is returned:

```
TenancyTenant.find_by(tenancy_id: 1)
TenancyTenant.find_by(tenant_id: 1)
TenancyTenant.find_by(id: 11)
TenancyTenant.find_by(id: 11, tenancy_id: 1)
TenancyTenant.where(tenancy_id: 1, tenant_id: 1)
```

However, when I use:

```
TenancyTenant.find_by(tenant_id: 1, tenancy_id: 1)
```

then it returns nil.

Please can anyone advise me as to why this behaviour may be occurring?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the SQL generated?

Comment: Add `to_sql` to the queries, output the generated SQL and compare it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ActiveRecord has cached result for `TenancyTenant.find_by(tenant_id: 1, tenancy_id: 1)`. Try to perform the same query in an `uncached` block:

```
TenancyTenant.uncached do
  TenancyTenant.find_by(tenant_id: 1, tenancy_id: 1)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem actually went away by itself and unfortunately I can't seem to recreate it, but I'll certainly bear your solution in mind if it occurs again. Thank you